# My if elif code is ignoring the elif part

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Here is part of my code that has the if elif statement. For some reason the code outputs the if statement when called but ignores the elif when called. Please help:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) == 32: # 32 is also equal to spacebar. 
    break
elif cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: # 27 is equal to escape
    name = input("Name the file:")
    testimage = ("'%s'.jpg".format(img_counter) %name) 
    cv2.imwrite(testimage, frame)
    print("Picture saved!")
    img_counter += 1
    choice = input("Do you want to post to facebook?(Y/n)")
    if choice == 'Y':
        print("Posting now!")
    elif choice == 'n':
        print("Ok not posting.")
```

Comment: I think you probably want to capture the input once, outside the if statement, then test the return value, rather than making two separate calls to cv2.waitKey().

Comment: The elif at the top, or the elif at the bottom of your code? The first one doesn't have output, so I'm guessing your question is about the bottom elif, but please clarify.

Comment: Is that even valid code? Admittedly, it's been a while since I've done Python seriously but doesn't the first `if` section need a `pass`?

Comment: The formatting is wrong too. You're mixing the old string interpolation (%) with the newer one.

Comment: I accidentally forgot to include the break command in the first if statement. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

When the key is pressed, you have one opportunity to capture its value. As written, you are attempting to "live-read" the keypress in the context of the *if* block. The problem is that once the condition is evaluated, the keypress is over and the *if* block is exited. It will never reach the *elif* section. Consider capturing the value in a variable (as Jim Lewis recommended in the comments), then test that variable's value.

Concerning your code sample, there is nothing occurring when 32 is true. Is this just an incomplete code snippet to illustrate your issue? If so disregard. Otherwise, you could probably write it as follows:

```
keyPressed = cv2.waitKey(1)
if keyPressed == 27:
    name = input("Name the file:")
    testimage = ("'%s'.jpg".format(img_counter) %name)
    cv2.imwrite(testimage, frame)
    print("Picture saved!")
    img_counter += 1
    choice = input("Do you want to post to facebook? (Y/n)")

if choice == 'Y':
    print("Posting now!")
else:
    print("Ok not posting.")
```